# Spring NoSuchBeanDefinitationException throw after exporting jar file

Tags: java, spring, jar

I have spring project and I can get the spring bean from the spring context before exporting jar file. I export the jar file and run that jar file on the cmd. I got the `NoSuchBeanDefinitationException`. the project cannot find the spring bean. I used `<context:component-scan>` in spring configuration file. I would like to know what is the problem is?

**Edit**

In the bean

```
package com.example.userprofile;

@Service("UserProfileManager")
@Transactional
public class UserProfileManagerImpl implements UserProfileManager{

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileDao userProfileDao;
```

In the spring configuration file

```
<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.example" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />


<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/test"
        p:username="root" p:password="root" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When I test the project with JBoss IDE, it works perfectly. But when I export the project into the jar file and run on the cmd. I got the following error.
[image]

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9GZuKV7cDNsM1ZVWVlJZGctRE0/edit?usp=sharing) is my project zip file. I am sorry for late updating.

Comment: can u paste the list of jars that you have used?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: Please add your configuration xml and JAR layout.

Comment: Can you add the code of UserProfileManager please?

Comment: I confused that why does the exception throw when I run the project jar file?

Comment: package name of UserProfileManagerImpl class ?

Comment: Is the class where you autowire this bean also a spring bean? Will this application work in yor IDE?

Comment: yes. there is bean class. Sure! worked perfectly on IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Though the problem statement is too wide to provide a specific answer, you can do the following:

1. Open your jar file to make sure your class is there with all the annotations.
2. Check the packaged jar to make sure you have all the needed libraries.
3. Check your class path in the command line to make sure if you are referring to the paths of your libs.
4. If you're using a build script, check for the scopes of dependent libraries and see you are exporting all the needed jars.

And if nothing jumps out, paste your entire stack trace and not just the snippet and also how your jar is structured so that we also see the same big picture as you do.

Comment: Tip: Look at the output in the IDE to see the classpath it uses to run, and compare that to your classpath.
I bet on suggestion 1.

Comment: how to check the classes annotation in jar file?